# Sum rows values one after the other

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that describes, for every second from 1 to 120, and for every nodeId from 0 to 8, the distance from one node to the previous one (the distance from nodeId 8 to nodeId 7, from 7 to 6, ..., from 1 to 0). Basically it looks like this:

```
    time nodeId distance
1      1      0 0.000000
2      1      1 5.007664
3      1      2 5.001861
4      1      3 5.001778
5      1      4 5.001755
6      1      5 5.001719
7      1      6 5.001714
8      1      7 5.001647
9      1      8 5.001608
289    2      0 0.000000
290    2      1 5.026168
291    2      2 5.007968
292    2      3 5.007372
293    2      4 5.008111
294    2      5 5.009455
```

I'd like to change the distance column so that it tells me the distance from nodeId 0 for every nodeId, and for every second. 

So, for example, the distance of nodeId==2 on time==1 should be the distance of nodeId==2 plus nodeId==1 (where time==1), and then from there I need to start summing the other values with the previous ones, for example 
(nodeId==3 should be nodeId==3+nodeId==2)

I've tried to use a for loop but I can't figure out how to sum the values I need without using a lot of ifs (basically one for every nodeId-time).

The result on this DataFrame should look like this:

```
    time nodeId distance
1      1      0 0.000000
2      1      1 5.007664
3      1      2 10.00953
4      1      3 15.01131
5      1      4 20.01307
6      1      5 25.01479
7      1      6 30.01650
8      1      7 35.01815
9      1      8 40.01976
289    2      0 0.000000
290    2      1 5.026168
291    2      2 10.03414
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you simply need `cumsum` grouped by `time`. -

In base R -

```
df$d2 <- with(df, ave(distance, time, FUN = cumsum))

    time nodeId distance        d2
1      1      0 0.000000  0.000000
2      1      1 5.007664  5.007664
3      1      2 5.001861 10.009525
4      1      3 5.001778 15.011303
5      1      4 5.001755 20.013058
6      1      5 5.001719 25.014777
7      1      6 5.001714 30.016491
8      1      7 5.001647 35.018138
9      1      8 5.001608 40.019746
289    2      0 0.000000  0.000000
290    2      1 5.026168  5.026168
291    2      2 5.007968 10.034136
292    2      3 5.007372 15.041508
293    2      4 5.008111 20.049619
294    2      5 5.009455 25.059074
```

With `dplyr` -

```
df %>% group_by(time) %>% mutate(d2 = cumsum(distance)) %>% ungroup()
```

With `data.table` -

```
setDT(df)[, d2 := cumsum(distance), by = time][]
```